# find german phone numbers in a text

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I want to find phone numbers (written in a german way) in a text. I almost finished my javascript regex to find them.
This is the regular expression:

```
(((((((00|\+)[0-9]{1,3}[ \-/]?)|0)[ ]?[1-9][0-9]{1,4})[ ]?[\-/]?[ ]?)|((((00|\+)[0-9]{1,3}[ ]?\()|\(0)(\)|[ ]?[1-9][0-9]{1,4}\))[ ]?[\-/]?[ ]?))[0-9]{1,7}([ \-/]?[0-9]{1,5}){0,4})
```

But now I want to add 2 more things:

1. It should exclude phone numbers with less than 9 digits.  I tried to
   add **(?=(.*?\d){9,})** in front of the whole expression. That solution
   works for **01234** but not for **+33 (33) 3)** if there are some more
   numbers following. So what is my mistake?
2. It should exclude numbers without any whitespace (like **+49123123123**). How can I realize that?

To understand better what my intention is, I prepared a demo: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rS6qM7/3)

Test case:

```
+33 (33) 3)44444444444 //the found string has only 5 digits, but it shouldn't be found because of (?=(.*?\d){9,})
+49123123123 //how can I exclude that, because there is no white space in the middle

// this is the part where I test all the other phone numbers, if you are interested in:

//it should match these phone numbers:
testword +49 30 12345-67 testword 
testword+49 (0)30 12345-67
(0)30 12345-67
(0)30 123 234
(0123)30 12345-67
test (021)30 123 234
s030 12345-67 dsd
(030) 12345 55 99testword 
testword   (030) 12345 44
0351 4640-123
09623 12 3 33
09234 1233
+49 123 1 2 12 31
0049 2123 1231
+1 3519 1231
0 30 / 12 34 56
0 30 / 12 34 56
030 / 12 34 56
0123 / 12312 123
testword  0178 1232231
+490 178 1232231
testword +36 (351)4740-991 testword
testword +36(351) 4740-991 testword
09623 12333 testword

should NOT match (with the reason why it shouldn't match):
+49123123123 //because there is no white space
01781232231 //because there is no white space
123456 //because it doesn't have at least 9 digits and no white space
123.123 //because it has a dot
12-12-12 //because there is no white space and there is more than one dash
12-12 -12-12-12 //because there is more than one dash
1990 - 2000 //because it doesn't have at least 9 digits
1990-2000 //because it doesn't have at least 9 digits and no white space
1990-91 //because it doesn't have at least 9 digits and no white space
123 //because it doesn't have at least 9 digits and no white space
+36 (351) 47(40-991 //because it has more than one left bracket
+36 (33) 3)4444
)40-991 //because it has more than one right bracket
+23+234 +2346 // because it has more than one plus sign
234 234 234 234   234 // because it has more than one white space in a row
123   123123 // because it has more than one white space in a row
01712123123
01234
```

Comment: The Cthulhu is real.

Comment: I think you should take care of the other 2 conditions (or at least the minimal digit condition) after you got the matches. Checking all of them in a single regex will inflate the size of the regex. (Basically, since you can't check your condition in a look-ahead, you need to mix it in with the current regex using theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using 2 patterns
1st to capture allowed characters :

```
(?!\s)(\+?[0-9 .\/()-]{8,}\d)\b        # optional `+`, 8 or more allowed chr's, digit
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/188)

then 2nd to capture your criteria:

```
^(?=.*\h)                              # has at least one whitespace
(?!.*\h\h)                             # does not see double whitespaces
(?!.*-.*-)                             # does not see more than one `-`
(?=(?:.*\d){9,})                       # has at least 9 digits
([^(\r\n]*\(?[^)\r\n]+\)?[^()\r\n]+)$  # sees optional proper parentheses
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE7tA1/2)

Comment: Thank you! Ok I will use 2 Patterns.
By the way your second regex doesn't work in Javascript --> this is for Javascript: [Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/zE7tA1/3)

Comment: @TheSchecke use this instead `^(?=.* )(?!.*  )(?!.*-.*-)(?=(?:.*\d){9,})([^(\r\n]*\(?[^)\r\n]+\)?[^()\r\n]+)$`